# All Lie subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

I want to describe all Lie subgroups of the real line.
I know that it is the same as to describe all closed subgroups and I know how to do that for $S^1$. Next I wanted to consider $$\pi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R/Z} = S^1 $$
and look at $\pi^{-1}(subgruops)$ but a problem occurs: I need this map to be closed (take closed subsets to closed) but it is not.

Can I modify this proof to make it work or do I need something different?( I know that there are different approaches but I want to fix mine)

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't work: the group $\sqrt{2}\mathbb Z$ is a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb R$, but under the mapping $\pi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z = S^1$ it does not get taken to a closed subgroup of $S^1$.

Comment: It is exactly what I was talking about. It doesn’t work because it isn’t closed map, but maybe we can do something like $ \pi(x) = e^{irx} $ where $r$ is irrational ?

Comment: Sure, and that allows you to prove that $\sqrt{2}\mathbb Z$ is a closed subgroup, but the whole point is that you want to classify *all* closed subgroups: in order to modify this approach you'd have to prove that for each closed subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb R$ there is a smooth homomorphism $\pi: \mathbb R \to S^1$ and a closed subgroup $G'$ of $S^1$ so that $G = \pi^{-1}(G')$; but I don't see a way to do this without classifying the Lie subgroups of $\mathbb R$ first. But maybe I'm just telling you things you already know?